# Java : eclipse, console doesn't display method failed step

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, methods, testng

As seen in the image, every time when I run the test, only the test class failed step is displayed in the console. It doesn't display the method step where it failed. I used to get the method failed line number in the console before but not sure what made this go away now.
[734 orgPortal.satisfyAllconditionOfSanctions(); step failed is displayed in the console but it is not displayed where it has failed in the method ie satisfyAllcondtionOfSanctions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBTlZ.png)

Comment: The exception doesn't get thrown inside the method. It gets thrown while calling the method. Which means something is wrong with `orgPortal`.